# The" Interface" on Qjackctl is grayed out, how do I fix this?

Tags: settings, interface

I was working with Qjackctl and for some reason the Interface button in the settings area is grayed out. It looks like this:

[image: Interface.png]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I would like to check to make sure that the interface is set correctly. Thank you all in advance for all of your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. To make it so that the interface is not grayed out, go to this setting in Qjackctl.

[image: settings.png]

Then, click on the "up" arrow and go to dummy, then scroll back down to alsa. That will make it so that the interface is not grayed out.

Comment: Had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 with Qjackctl 0.3.10, and this solved it.